# How does Typescript change the method definition?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Typescript Version: `"^2.9.2"`.

This is my code.

Define method new interface:

```
interface TestRoute<R,F>{
    to(r:R):F;
    defaultRoute:F;
}
```

My global space:

```
declare global {
    interface UserRpc {
        connector: {
            authRemoter:{
                updateNickName:TestRoute<FrontendSession,typeof AuthRemoter.prototype.updateNickName>;
                auth:TestRoute<FrontendSession,typeof AuthRemoter.prototype.auth>;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The class I defined:

```
@Component()
export class AuthRemoter extends RemoteAbstract{
    constructor(@Inject(PROVIDERS.PINUS_APP) private readonly app:Application) {
        super();
    }


    public async auth(username: string , password: string) {
        return true;
    }

    public async updateNickName(uid:string,surname:string){
        const connectionService = this.app.components.__connection__;
        connectionService.updateUserInfo(uid,{username:surname} as any);
        return true;
    }

}
```

How do you elegantly define the `global.UserRpc.connector.authRemoter` interface so that you don't need to call `TestRoute` for each method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of method names you want to include, you can use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) to iterate over them and transform the values the way you want:

```
type TestRoutify<T, K extends keyof T> = 
  {[P in K]: TestRoute<FrontendSession, T[K]>}

interface UserRpc {
  connector: {
    authRemoter: TestRoutify<AuthRemoter, 'auth'|'updateNickName'>
  }
}
```

You can verify that this evaluates to the same type as the `UserRpc` in your code above.

---

If you don't want to have to manually list out the method names as in  `'auth'|'updateNickName'`, then you need some way to pick those names out of the `AuthRemoter` type.  For example, if the criterion you're using is "all methods of `AuthRemoter`", then you can do something like this using [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types):

```
type FunctionKeys<T> = 
  {[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? K : never}[keyof T]
```

So `FunctionKeys<AuthRemoter>` will evaluate to `'auth' | 'updateNickName'` along with any extra method names in `RemoteAbstract`.  If `RemoteAbstract` doesn't have any extra methods or you don't mind including them:

```
type TestRoutifyMethods<T> = TestRoutify<T, FunctionKeys<T>>;

interface UserRpc {
  connector: {
    authRemoter: TestRoutifyMethods<AuthRemoter>
  }
}
```

If that ends up pulling in methods you don't want, then you can try to come up with a conditional type that better represents your selection criterion, or just give up and specify the keys manually as in the first solution above.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This two method all works well.